# What is the dependency between GitLab executor and git strategy?

Tags: gitlab

It is possible to set [GIT_STRATEGY](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-strategy) variable for a pipeline which should define if repo will be cloned or fetched before each job. According to [workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/#runner-execution-flow) cloning/fetching is done by executors.

Does the fact that repo will be fetched or cloned also depend on `Reuse previous clone if it exists` [executors' ability](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/#selecting-the-executor)?